# How to replace all spaces except those appearing after a TeX command?

Tags: bash, sed, replace

I have a file, `file1.tex`, containing TeX commands, like `\em` and `\par`. All of the commands are in the format `\` + some string of uppercase and lowercase letters from A-Z and are all followed by a space.

I need to use a command like this, which replaces all spaces with `\`, a slash and a space.

```
sed -i "s/\ /\\\\\ /g" ./file1.tex
```

I do not want these to replace the empty spaces which appear immediately after TeX commands though. For example, I want this:

```
\noindent This is a sentence {\em which has some words}.
This is another \hfill sentence \ldots with some more words.
```

To become:

```
\noindent This\ is\ a\ sentence\ {\em which\ has\ some\ words}.
This\ is\ another\ \hfill sentence\ \ldots with\ some\ more\ words.
```

How can I replace all spaces, except those appearing after any command taking the form of `\sometext`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `sed` doesn't support look-behind, I think this will be a lot easier using Perl.

```
$ perl -pe 's/\b(?<!\\)(\w+)\b /$1\\ /g' texfile
\noindent This\ is\ a\ sentence\ {\em which\ has\ some\ words}.
This\ is\ another\ \hfill sentence\ \ldots with\ some\ more\ words.
```

To make the changes permanent to the file in-place:

```
perl -pi -e 's/\b(?<!\\)(\w+)\b /$1\\ /g' texfile
```

Explanation:

The regex matches a word which does not start with a backslash which is followed by a space.

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?<!` - begin a non-capturing negative look-behind (don't match)
- `\\` - escaped backslash
- `)` - close the look-behind
- `(` - begin a capture group
- `\w+` - match one or more word characters (alphanumeric plus underscore)
- `)` - close the capture group
- `$1` - copy the capture group into the replacement
- `\\` - add a backslash
- `g` - do the substitution globally

I left a couple things out of the list which should be self-evident.

Comment: @jordanm: You're missing a few zeros, but post something better!

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
 sed -i 's/\(\\[^ ]*\) /\1\n/g;s/ /\\ /g;y/\n/ /' file
```

Explanation:

- Replace all single spaces following a command with a newline. `s/\(\\[^ ]*\) /\1\n/g`
- Prepend all other spaces with  a `\`. `s/ /\\ /g`
- Replace all newlines with spaces. `y/\n/ /`

Comment: On reflection `sed 's/ /\\ /g;s/\(\\[^ ]*\)\\/\1/g' file` might work.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `awk` like this:

`awk '{ for (i=1; i<NF; i++) if ($i ~ /\\/) printf "%s ", $i; else if ($i !~ /\\/) printf "%s\\ ", $i; printf $NF"\n" }' file.tex`

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Replace the space at the end of the TeX commands with some recognizable text, add the slashes before all spaces, and finally remove the text you've added. For example:

```
s;\(\\[[:alpha:]]\{1,\}\);\1{};g
s; ;\\ ;g
s;\(\\[[:alpha:]]\{1,\}\){};\1 ;g
```

Here, I've chosen to add `{}` to the end of the TeX commands, which is safe because you know that no TeX commands are present with that structure.